# Relation between crossover freqquency of loop gain and closed loop's corner frequency when feedback is not unity

Tags: circuit-analysis, switch-mode-power-supply, circuit-design, feedback, loop-gain

In this [Control Loop Cookbook](https://www.ti.com/seclit/ml/slup113/slup113.pdf) from TI, in the red box the author said that **the crossover frequency (indicated in figure 2) of the open-loop is same as 3dB down frequency or corner frequency of the closed loop**.

However, I don't think this statement is correct with the specific case in figure 2. The statement is only correct if feedback factor Kfb is unity. But from the closed-loop gain, we can infer that Kfb is not 1 (Kfb = 0.5).

What do you think about this? Is the article wrong? In general case, the crossover frequency of open-loop fc(actually I think call it "loop gain" is more accurate) makes the closed loop corner frequency at Kfb*fc.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to me either.

Comment: So do you agree with my conclusion? With that system above, Kfb =0.5 and the crossover frequency of loop gain fc, the closed-loop gain 3dB corner frequency should be Kfb*fc or 0.5fc not fc as the article.

Comment: I don’t think the figure 2 is that great either because they show the closed loop gain remaining higher at frequencies higher than the open loop gain can sustain.

Answer (score 1):

**It is not a mistake, the author is correct.**

> ..at \$\ f_c\$ (where \$\ T=1\$, with associated \$ 90^{\circ}\$. phase lag), the closed loop gain \$\ G(s)\$ is 3dB down..

Let \$\ T=1\angle90^{\circ}=\cos(90^{\circ})+j\sin(90^{\circ})=j\$

The closed-loop transfer function is:

\$\ G(s) = \frac{1}{K_{FB}} \cdot \frac{T}{1+T}\$

Substituting \$\ T=j\$ and solving for the gain:

\$\ |G(s)|= \frac{1}{K_{FB}} \cdot |\frac{j}{1+j}|=\frac{1}{K_{FB}} \cdot |\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}j|=\frac{1}{K_{FB}} \cdot \sqrt{(\frac{1}{2})^2+(\frac{1}{2})^2}=\frac{1}{K_{FB}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\$

\$\ 20 \cdot \log_{10}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})=-3 \$ [dB]

As the author stated; when the open loop gain \$\ T(s)\$ equals one, with associated \$ 90^{\circ}\$ phase lag, the closed loop gain \$\ G(s)\$ is down 3dB, or \$\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\$

Comment: I can't follow your maths but with a closed loop gain of 2 the closed loop gain is down 3dB when the open loop gain is also equal to 2 (not 1).

Comment: G(s) = T/(1+(0.5T))

Comment: No, not true, the closed loop gain is down 3db when the open loop gain T(s), as defined by the author, is equal to 1 with an angle of 90deg, or in other words when T(s) =j..

Comment: Ah! I see where the confusion is. "As defined by the author" is the crux. What the author calls the "open loop" gain is usually referred to as the "loop" gain. By conventional definition the "open loop" gain is the forward loop gain or Vout/Vdiff for an op amp and the "loop" gain is the gain right around the loop. I agree that where the loop gain in the usual sense, (open loop gain in the author's sense), is unity, the closed loop gain is down -3dB whatever the value of the low frequency closed loop gain.

Comment: Yes exactly, as I wrote; when \$\ T=1\angle 90^{\circ}\$ then \$\ G(s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}G_0 \$.. \$\ T \$ is what the author calles the open loop gain, and I agree that I would have called this the loop gain. So the statements the author make are all completely true and accurate, and the math holds true, the confusion comes from two facts; the author used the term "open loop gain" instead of "loop gain" and also the author uses the term "gain" when he means "transfer function" the gain is not the transfer function it self but the magnitude of the transfer function.

Comment: ..So I agree that the author is using confusing terms/language, but if you read what he is saying carefully you will find that it all holds true.

Comment: and it doesn't help clarity that he uses T for his open loop transfer function (what is normally called "loop") when T(s) is often used for closed loop and he uses G(s) for closed loop when G(s) is conventionally used for the forward loop (conventionally the open loop).

Comment: Yes I agree completely, he did not make the text easy to digest at all, I would not be surprised if the OP is not the only one who has been confused by this text.

Comment: @James I just wanted to add that actually, strictly speaking, the author is correct in calling it the "open loop gain" (what you and I have taken to calling the "loop gain"). That is because in control theory, the "open loop gain" IS actually defined as the gain seen at the inverting node (after all feedback gains) when the inverting terminal is disconnected, and the input is fed directly into the forward gain block, which is usually denoted \$\ G(s)\$ (what we take to calling the "open loop gain").

Comment: Yes, I have seen that definition of open loop gain used in control theory books. It is the same as 'our' loop gain except that the inversion through the inverting input is not included. So B.Aol instead of -B.Aol. The author says that his open loop gain, T is the "total gain around the entire feedback loop" but he doesn't include the inversion of the inverting input. I now understand your maths but I'd be happier if you'd used -90 degs instead of +90 degs. It makes no difference to the magnitude result but gives an incorrect result of +45 degs phase instead of the correct -45 degs phase.

Comment: All in all a very interesting piece by the author and goes a good way towards describing how to compensate a regulator.